# passing typdef struct as a parameter to the function

Tags: c, function, struct, typedef

When i run this code i got this error :
[Error] subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*Defined a data type named User with typedef*/
typedef struct User{
    char firstName[50];
    char lastName[50];
    int phonenumber; 
}user;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    user users[2];/*users defined "user" type*/

    strcpy(users[0].firstName,"furkan");

    strcpy(users[1].lastName,"xxxx");

    users[0].phonenumber = 1;

    users[1].phonenumber = 2 ;

    print_users(users);

    return 0;
}

/*Function for printing user type users values*/
void print_users(user usr)
{
    int j=0;

    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        printf("%-10s%-20s%7d\n",usr[j].firstName,usr[j].lastName,usr[j].phonenumber);
    }
}
```

I can make this function without typedef but i wonder if there is a way to make this happen

Comment: Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), learn to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and consult your [Rubber Duck](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: pass by pointer with the length of the array struct

Answer (score 1):

```
void print_users(user *usr)
```

this should be the parameters that your function receive, because inside your function you're acessing usr[j], so that means that usr need to be a pointer and not a structure itself.

ah, just to say, your for goes from 0 to 9 (10 positions), and your only allocated 2 positions.

Comment: Please don't just provide the code but *explain* what the mistake of the OP was.

Comment: Thank you Gabriel,  that solved the problem and i also corrected for loop counter.

Answer (score 1):

The function parameter

```
void print_users(user usr);
                 ^^^^^^^
```

is a scalar object. You may not apply the subscript operator for a scalar object.

If you want that the function deals with an array then you should declare the function at least like

```
void print_users(user usr[]);
                 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Take into account that it is not clear why the function uses magic number 10.

```
for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        ^^^^^
```

At the same time in the main you declared an array of only two elements

```
user users[2];
```

Thus it will be correctly to declare the function like

```
void print_users(user usr[], size_t n );
```

and to use the variable `n` in the loop

```
for(j=0;j < n;j++)
        ^^^^^
```

Correspondingly the function can be called like

```
print_users( users, 2 );
```